# Executing VoiceOver Command in JXA

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility, voiceover, javascript-automation

The following AppleScript works.

```
tell application "VoiceOver"
    tell commander to perform command "item chooser"
end tell
```

However, the following JXA throws an error: "Error 6: An error occurred."

```
vo = Application("VoiceOver")
vo.commander.performCommand("item chooser")
```